# Animate opacity hide / show

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, opacity, show

so, what is the different between:

**A)** (work for me)

```
... .animate({opacity: "show", marginTop: "25"}); ...
```

...

**B** (doesn´t work for me)

```
... .animate({opacity: "1", marginTop: "25"}); ...
```

e.g http://jsbin.com/iquwuc/6/edit#preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `hide()` that's roughly equivalent to `.css('display', 'none')`, so later changing opacity back to 1 changes the opacity of a hidden element. And that's why `show()` works - because it makes the element block again.

Comment: +1 for explaining the difference of `'show'` and `1` in this context. [ref](http://api.jquery.com/animate/): *In addition to numeric values, each property can take the strings 'show', 'hide', and 'toggle'. These shortcuts allow for custom hiding and showing animations that take into account the display type of the element.*

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are show and hiding, instead of animating the opacity. (Kinda obvious :P ).

**Edited code :** http://jsbin.com/iquwuc/11/edit#preview

You can make the following amendments to use the opacity setting:

**Add the following css:**

```
.sub-menu li#access ul {opacity:0; display:none;}
```

**And change your script to this:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.sub-menu').hover(function(){ 
          $('.sub-menu li#access ul').show();
        $('.sub-menu li#access ul').stop().animate({opacity: 1, marginTop: "25"}, 500);
        },
        function() {
                  $('.sub-menu li#access ul').stop().animate({opacity: 0, marginTop: "10"}, 500,function(){
                  $('.sub-menu li#access ul').hide();
                  });   
        });
});
```

**Basically what is happening is:**

On hover, you are SHOW'ing the dropdown with opacity 0, then animation happens to set margin and opacity. and on hover-out, animating opacity to 0 and HIDE'ing it again.

Answer (score 1):

in the css file or inline. Set the id or class to

inline -    `<div id="myid" style="opacity:0;"></div>`

in css

```
        #myid { opacity: 0; }
        .myclass {opacity: 0; }
```

that way when calling the animate opacity from jQuery it will function other wise your just calling an animation that is already at 1 opacity

Answer (score 0):

I would use dojo bibliothek for it (http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/animateProperty.html). You will find in DOJO more than only animating functionality, this framework offers a lot of components to solve big area of different problems.